# Laravel Corrupted Files - Files contain temporary path?

Tags: php, laravel, file, upload, flysystem

I'm currently developing a content management system using Laravel, however I am coming across a very strange issue...

```php
//If an asset was provided
$asset = $request->file('asset');
if($asset) {
  //Set the file name.
  $fileName = $asset->getClientOriginalName();
  //If we could move the uplaoded asset.
  if(Storage::disk('local')->put('presentation_assets/'.$fileName, $asset)) {
    //Save the file name in the database.
    $presentation->asset = $fileName;
  }
}
```

The above code successfully uploads the file and places it into the directory, and then proceeds to save the filename in the database, however the file becomes corrupt.

When uploading a test.txt file, the upload succeeds, however when examined on the server, the file contents is changed to the temporary path (see below)?????

```text
/tmp/phpkTe9NX
```

Can anyone shed some light onto why this would happen? I'm completely stumped!

Thanks for your help,

Alex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aha! Turns out I needed to use file_get_contents($asset) on the Storage::put() function. It all makes sense now! :)

Comment: explain, example? also... huh?